# How can I add HTML formatting to the comments box in the order admin area in Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, orders, html

Is there a way I can add html formatting to the order comments within the admin area? Just writing the comments using html doesn't work...

[image: Add comments section in admin order]

Comment: I think you'd have to modify the controller, for it not to be interpreted as plain text.

Comment: And you will need to do it in a manner that does not result in XSS/Cross site scripting attacks. If you have order comments enabled on the front end, it's an ideal method to attack the backend when html display has been enabled.